# Apache tomcat server is stopped after several commit of documents in Solr 4.4

Tags: tomcat, solr, solrnet, solr4

We have successfully installed Solr 4.4. We have done setup in windows 7. With the tomcat 8.0, Java jre 7 and Solr 4.4. 
We have done commit for some documents. But unfortunately after some commit of document our Apache tomcat server is stopped. And at time we get the following error in application.

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size) at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size) at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean
>   async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state) at System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at
>   SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.CopyTo(Stream input, Stream output) at
>   SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String
>   contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at
>   SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s) at
>   SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd) at
>   ....

Comment: Which version of Tomcat 8 are you using and which connector are you using?

Comment: Also you need to check the Solr/Tomcat logs.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer, unfortunately no error is logged in Solr log.

Comment: @MarkThomas : Tomcat 8.0.0 and connector is Solrnet 4.0

Comment: There is no such Tomcat version as 8.0.0. To date there have only been release candidates for 8.0.x and they have a more specific version number. By connector, I meant which HTTP/AJP connector(s) are configured in server.xml and which ones are you using when you see this issue.

Comment: @MarkThomas We also tried on Apache tomcat 7.0.42 Version. But we got the same issue. Please advice us.

Comment: @MarkThomas: We haven't changed any connector.So, It will be a default one.

Comment: OK. That rules out a few possibilities. Has Tomcat shutdown gracefully, has the processed crashed (check the logs) or something else?

Comment: Something is terribly wrong, here: your stack trace looks like a .NET stack trace. That is... it's simply not Java. Are you sure you are using Java here at all? You are going to need to post some logs from Tomcat instead of from a client error.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz : Yes this this .NET stack trace. We are using Solrnet.

Comment: ... and so the server-side error messages are... what, exactly?

Comment: You need to get to the Tomcat logs. Otherwise nobody can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it might be issue of network or invalid data.

I had an same issue. I was checked my network and there was some security issues.You should check your network settings.