# Solr goes down on trying to add document

Tags: solr, solrj, solrnet, solr4, solrcloud

Solr 4 stopped immediately on trying to add document and commit. I'm working on a Solr 4 with Tomcat 8 on Windows 7, and the Solr has only one core that I use. On trying to commit the document from SolrNet, however the Solr and Tomcat both goes down. I noticed few documents commited, but didn't find any error in Solr log.

Note that this is a new Tomcat & Solr installation.

On application side using SolrNet on adding document, I get following error:

System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

**Update**
I have tried with uninstalling Tomcat 8 and installed Tomcat 7 with Solr4 but the issue is still the same.

Any help is highly appreciated on what could be wrong? What to check? Where to find errors has caused this?

Also let me know if you need more details.

Thanks

Comment: Seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138200/apache-tomcat-server-is-stopped-after-several-commit-of-documents-in-solr-4-4 . Also, if Solr goes down with a simple request, then it definitely sounds like an issue with the web container (Tomcat), so you should check out the container's logs. Or try Jetty instead.

Comment: Thank you for providing us update on this. I'm monitoring that issue as well, its very similar to what I'm facing. I have checked the tomcat logs but not found any errors logged in it. If it gives some error, it can be fixed, but somehow we aren't getting any errors logged into tomcat or Solr logs!

Comment: Try the same request that makes Tomcat fail using Jetty instead.

Comment: Hi, tried with jetty, it was the same. We think the issue with that particular server! We changed to another server and everything was working just fine.

Comment: Any idea how to close this question?

Comment: answer yourself (please include all details about your experience and solution), then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat 8 does not have a stable release yet and Solr has not been tested with it. There may be some incompatibilities. Please try with Tomcat 7 to rule out issues with Tomcat 8.

Moreover, the last release of SolrNet was made about 2 years ago - I am not sure if it will work well with the latest release of Solr. I think you should use SolrJ if possible. Otherwise, just post the Solr docs as XML.

Comment: Yes, SolrNet *does* work with the latest Solr. Also, SolrJ is for JVM, while SolrNet is for .NET, you can't "use SolrJ instead of SolrNet".

Comment: Okay, I have already tried with Tomcat 7 and used Solr 4. But the issue is still same. Moreover, what is the last version of Solr supported by SolrNet?

Comment: Any idea? Its really very frustrating as no matter what we do its still the same.